# Multiple Hash table objects into single Object or Array?

Tags: android, arrays, hashtable

I have 10 hash tables, i need to store all these 10 hash tables into single instance like array. and i want to pass selected hash table into another class/Activity. 
How can i do this? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem as follows

```
 List<Hashtable<String, String>> info = new ArrayList<Hashtable<String, String>>();
```

In Loop

```
    Hashtable<String, String> hm = new Hashtable<String, String>();
// Put elements to the map

hm.put("Read_Flag", s1);
hm.put("sms_received_id", s2);
hm.put("Sender_Id", s3);
hm.put("Sender_Name", s4);
hm.put("Patient_Name", s5);
hm.put("Received_Date", s6);
hm.put("Received_Text", s7);
hm.put("Received_Text_Full", s8);
hm.put("AttachmentFlag", s9);

// Get a set of the entries
Set<?> set = hm.entrySet();
// Get an iterator
Iterator<?> it = set.iterator();
// Display elements
while(it.hasNext()) {
Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)it.next();

}
//System.out.println(hm);

info.add(hm);
```

// loop ends

Answer (score 2):

Create your class:

```
public class Maps implements Parcelable {
    Map[] mapArray = new Map[10];

    public Map[] getMapArray() {
        return mapArray;
    }

    public void setMapArray(Map[] mapArray) {
        this.mapArray = mapArray;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Then in activity do next things:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(); // create intent that call your another activity
 Maps maps = new Maps(); // create maps object.
 maps.getMapArray();        // mark your selected maps
 intent.putExtra("Maps", maps); // put key for your object
 startActivity(intent);// start your another activity.
```

In another activity get this object by "Maps" key and work with it.

Comment: its ok for 10 hash table but how can we use more hashtables?

Comment: create method that increase your array and put more hashtables in it.

Comment: how to get that data in other class/intent?

Comment: Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        extras.getParcelable("Maps");